# Not understanding the solution to a multiple choice question on linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

[image]

I know B and F do not contain the zero element required for them to be subspaces and I understand D, the others I am unsure about A, C and E. I have another post asking about nullity relations which I will try to link below too

Any input is greatly appreciated, I just want to understand this fully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets from $A$ and $E$ are the *same* set. Actually, both sets are equal to the set $\mathcal L(\Bbb R^5,\Bbb R^4)$, since no linear map from $\Bbb R^5$ into $\Bbb R^4$ is injective. And $\mathcal L(\Bbb R^5,\Bbb R^4)$ is a vector space.

The set from $C$ is also a vector space, since it consists only of the null map.

Comment: Really in awe of this response, I cannot thank you enough.